# What is "Ar.1" in glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.Ar.1.x86_64

Tags: centos, gcc, glibc

For some reason my system has  `glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.Ar.1.x86_64` installed. Not sure what that **Ar.1** is doing there. I need to install **glibc-devel**, which complains because it requires `glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64` (*without* Ar.1). I can't find this package (with Ar.1) anywhere. Can I potentially rename glibc (remove Ar.1) without breaking the system? What are my options here? System is a pre-built qcow2 virtual image from Arista so reinstalling is not really an option. Based on Centos 7.9.

```
[veos-router1 tmp]$ sudo yum localinstall glibc-devel-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64 (/glibc-devel-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64)
           Requires: glibc = 2.17-324.el7_9
           Installed: glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.Ar.1.x86_64 (installed)
               glibc = 2.17-324.el7_9.Ar.1
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64 (/glibc-devel-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64)
           Requires: glibc-headers
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64 (/glibc-devel-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64)
           Requires: glibc-headers = 2.17-324.el7_9
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Reason I need glib-devel is because I'm trying to install gcc on system and gcc requires glib-devel.

Comment: *pre-built qcow2 virtual image from `Ar`ista* you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having a `.vendor_string.` embedded in the RPM package name is a typical pattern of RPMs coming out of Yocto's tooling.

> I need to install glibc-devel,

Then you need to get the yocto tree or an SDK from your hardware vendor¹. That glibc-devel has to be matching the actual glibc you're using, or is completely worthless.

Also, having a `-devel` package on your embedded machine is –– a bad idea, and an indication of you not using the embedded workflow that your vendor has foreseen.

Generally, the workflow is that you get the SDK from Arista for the very specific device you've got. That will include the correct glibc-devel – you really can't just drop in CentOS's glibc-devel, there's a difference between that and what you have installed, otherwise that `Ar.1` wouldn't be in that name.

---

Maybe this non-technical, more motivates-the-state-of-things [talk](https://archive.fosdem.org/2016/schedule/event/sdrembedded/) by Mr. Moritz Fischer, now doing much embedded stuff for a much bigger company helps a bit getting to understand what an SDK does for you as user.

Comment: You answered the question of where that Ar.1 string came from. Indeed from switch Vendor Arista. I downloaded the Router Image Src files from Arista and found a bunch of rpms that were tagged with "ar.1" string. I'll have a chat with them.